# Why am I getting an 'API token is missing' error?

Tags: sendbird

I am trying build a chat app in my android application. but is throwing an error message "API token is missing"...

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

[Check here](https://docs.sendbird.com/android/quick_start#3_send_your_first_message_4_step_1_initialize_the_chat_sdk) send the APP_ID while initialize sendbird `SendBird.init(APP_ID, Context context);`